# Sprite movement In Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently started messing with the Unity 5 Scripting API and I can't seem to make this piece of code work for my Simple Smiley Face Sprite1. All I want it to do is move slightly.  I have tried multiple solutions. I believe it is not accepting the key board button or it is not finding the sprite. Thank you for the help in advance!

...Super simple code, I am just experimenting.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey ("q")) {
            var Sprite1 = GameObject.Find("Sprite1");
            Sprite1.transform.Translate(1,3,5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What have you observed while debugging? Are there any error messages? This is not enough to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `KeyCode.Q`:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
{
    var Sprite1 = GameObject.Find("Sprite1");
    Sprite1.transform.Translate(1,3,5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward) * 10;
}`

you can simply add this code to your sprite and change the number 10 or any other the speed you want